# How do I cascade delete a collection in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, cascade, coldfusion-9

Let's say I have two entities, a `Post` and a `Comment` (in ColdFusion):

```
component persistent="true" table="post"
{
    property name="Id" fieldtype="id";
    property name="Comments" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Comment" fkcolumn="post_id" cascade="all";
}

component persistent="true" table="comment"
{
    property name="Id" fieldtype="id";
    property name="Post" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Post" column="post_id";
}
```

`Post` has a collection of `Comments`. Now I'd like to delete a `Post`, and have the `Comments` automatically deleted as well. I've tried the straightforward method:

```
var post = EntityLoadByPK("Post", 13);
EntityDelete(post);
```

But I'm getting a Hibernate error that says that `post_id` cannot be set to null. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: oh, Comments should be `cascade="all-delete-orphan"` instead.  And Don't forget to set one side to `inverse="true"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your mappings. Try making the Post property of comment not null and marking the Comments property of post as inverse.

```
component persistent="true" table="post"
{
  property name="Id" fieldtype="id";
  property name="Comments" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Comment" fkcolumn="post_id" cascade="all" inverse="true";
}

component persistent="true" table="comment"
{
  property name="Id" fieldtype="id";
  property name="Post" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Post" column="post_id" notnull="true";
}
```

Comment: I applied this to my tests and it started performing as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make post_id in Comment table nullable in your DB.  That's how hibernate does cascade delete.  It'll set all Comments with post_id = 13 as null, then delete all comments where post_id IS NULL

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the solution, considering that doing so breaks referential integrity.

Comment: I'd like to know if there's a better way too if there is one.

Comment: Inspired by this answer and its comments, I did a pretty thorough investigation of the configuration options and posted the results on my blog: http://fusiongrokker.com/post/on-cascaded-hibernate-deletes -- ultimately, after all of the different configuration combinations I tested, I found that there's _no way_ to get Hibernate to run something like `delete from comment where blog=1; delete from blog where id=1'` without using something like HQL. So it's possible to get the desired result, just not by using `entityDelete()`.